# Why use fixed length allocation instead of static allocation?

Tags: c, arrays, int, malloc

I understand that what I'm asking may be quite simple for some of you, but bear with me, I'm trying to understand memory management. Since we use a certain fixed length (N) for the size, why we also do this:

```
int *arr = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int))
```

..instead of the conventional static way:

```
int arr[N];
```

Comment: First one allocates from the heap, obviously. Second one will typically allocate from stack (may be implementation-defined, I don't know). If N is "large", first is preferred, otherwise option two. Stack space is more limited than heap space, typically.

Comment: Expanding on that, they have potentially different lifetimes. The memory for the first one exists until it is explicitly freed. The second one, if declare in a function, only exists within the function and is gone when the function exits.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError static storage duration not on the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` provides memory that remains available after execution of the block it is in ends, such as when the function it is in returns.

`int A[N]`, if it appears inside a function, uses memory that is guaranteed to be available only while execution of the block it is in has not ended. If it appears outside a function, the memory is available for all of program execution, but `N` must be a constant. (Further, even inside a function, `int A[N]` where `N` is not a constant is not supported in some C implementations.)

In typical C implementations in general-purpose operating systems, `malloc` has a large amount of memory available to provide, but `int A[N]` inside a function uses a stack region that is limited, commonly one to eight mebibytes total, depending on the system.

Comment: Looks like it's way cleaner in a way if I use malloc. Got more control to free, traverse or to manipulate the memory. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

`int arr[N];` goes either into static memory if it's in filescope (or is preceded by `static`) or on the stack.

A static-memory `int arr[N];` is cheapest to allocate (both in terms of size overhead and allocation time) but it can never be freed and the memory won't always be cache-local.

If the `int arr[N];` is inside a block (and not preceded by `static`), `int arr[N];` goes on the stack. This memory will pretty much certainly be cache-local, but you might not wish to use this form if `N` is large and your stack is limited (or you're risking stack overflow) or if the lifetime of `arr` needs to exceed that of its containing block.

`malloc`'d memory takes some time to allocate (tens to hundreds of ns), it may carry some size overhead, and the allocation may fail, but you can `free` the memory later and it stays until you do `free` it. It might also be resizable (via `realloc`) without the need to copy memory. Cache-locality-wise, it's sort of like static memory (i.e., the block may be potentially far from the cache-hot end of the stack).

So those are the considerations: **lifetime**, **stack size**, **allocation time**, **size overhead**, **free-ability**, and possibly **cache-locality**.

A final consideration might be a peculiar feature of C: **effective type**. A declared array has a fixed effective type  and therefore cannot be retyped without violating C's strict aliasing rules but `malloc`'d memory can be. In other words, you can use a `malloc`'d block as a backing storage for a generic allocator of your own, but a declared `char` array cannot be used that way, strictly speaking.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`malloc`. This is dynamic allocation. You can free or change the size of the allocated memory. Heap is usually much larger than the stack or global variables memory area. The memory has the same storage duration as static objects

The latter cannot be resized or freed (except the automatic objects by exiting the scope). Static and automatic storage is usually smaller than the heap.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you very much!

Comment: It is a little bit confusing to write *change the size of the allocated memory*... the memory block can be reallocated and the new address stored into the pointer.